# Python regular expression: how to split webs-pub-subscription-billme-clients-api-3.0.14.1.war

Tags: python, regex

I want to split 
webs-pub-subscription-billme-clients-api-3.0.14.1.war

to:

webs-pub-subscription-billme-clients-api

and 
3.0.14.1

how to split will be good in Python? thanks

Comment: How to split is heavily dependent on the expected format and what you want out of the string. You have not defined these things.

Comment: You should provide examples. A regex based on that one example is easy but there's no way to way to know about the rest of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'webs-pub-subscription-billme-clients-api-3.0.14.1.war'

# slice between the last dash, and the last dot:
print s[s.rfind('-')+1:s.rfind('.')]


# or, regex split on the last dash or the last dot 
# (a dash not followed by another dash, or a dot not followed by another dot)
# and take the middle chunk
import re
print re.split('-(?!.*-)|\.(?!.*\.)', s)[1]
```

[Try online at Repl.it](https://repl.it/Fxc0)

Comment: thanks so much for the help! teh 2nd proposal print(re.split('-(?!.*-)|\.(?!.*\.)', s)[1]) does not work, it show error as :                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Rt401.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(re.split('-(?!.*-)|\.(?!.*\.)', s)[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That means there is something as input which doesn't have a `-` or `.` and cannot be split, so it can't find the second piece. One of your input filenames / text lines doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be good like this :

```
import re
regex = r"(-)(?=[\d\.]+)"
test_str = "webs-pub-subscription-billme-clients-api-3.0.14.1.war"
subst = " "
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```